# populate drop down list with json

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying some stuff and populating drop down list with a json and javascript for some reason I am getting a console error when trying to populate

I am using `Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js`

this is the error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

> POST //localhost:9819/Home/Home/Test 404 (Not Found)
>   jquery-2.0.2.js:7858 send jquery-2.0.2.js:7858 jQuery.extend.ajax
>   jquery-2.0.2.js:7314 RetrieveData Index:45 (anonymous function)
>   Index:64 jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-2.0.2.js:4692 elemData.handle

This is the View Code:

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var Load = false;
        function RetrieveData() {
            if (Load == false) {
                Load = true;
                $.ajax({
                    url: <%= Url.Action("Test", "Home") %>
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#selectMe").html(data);
                        Load = false;
                    },
                    error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                        alert("Error: " + data);
                        Load = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        $(document).on("click", "#test", function () {
            RetrieveData();
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="submit" id="test" />
    <select id="selectMe"></select>
```

Controller:

```
public string GenerateHTMLforDropDownList(Dictionary<string, string> myData)
    {
        string HTMLString = "";

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> k in myData)
        {
            HTMLString += "<option value=\"" + k.Key + "\">" + k.Value + "</option>";
        }

        return HTMLString;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Test()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> myData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        myData.Add("0", "Mike");
        myData.Add("1", "Mark");
        myData.Add("2", "Karl");
        myData.Add("3", "Rhona");

        return Json(GenerateHTMLforDropDownList(myData), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

any help of how I can fix this thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, the resource is not found.  Look at the URL in the error:

```
http://localhost:9819/Home/Home/Test
```

Assuming you're not doing anything more custom, if you have a `Test` action on a `Home` controller then the URL *should* be:

```
http://localhost:9819/Home/Test
```

Notice also how you're specifying the URL in your code:

```
url: "Home/Test"
```

If you're currently at `http://localhost:9819/Home/Anything` then that relative URL says to look for a resource called `Test` in a "subdirectory" (using the word loosely) of the current resource.  So there's your problem.

Instead of specifying the URL manually like that, use the `Url.Action` method in MVC.  Something like this:

```
url: '@Url.Action("Test", "Home")'
```

This will generate a fully-qualified URL from server-side code regardless of where your current context is, so you don't have to adjust it based on the current URL or anything like that.

Comment: POST - localhost:9819/Home/@Url.Action(%22Test%22,%20%22Home%22) 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @BuyMyBet: Are you using Razor syntax (which is what I used) or the older syntax?  Is this genuinely an MVC view that's being pro-processed server-side?  The principle is the same, you need to replace your hard-coded relative URL with a dynamic one from the server.  The `Url.Action()` method is used to create this URL.

Comment: @BuyMyBet: Then try something more like: `<%= Url.Action("Test", "Home") %>` instead.  Regardless of the syntax, the principle is still the same.  The `Url.Action` method is made for exactly this purpose: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx  Alternatively, you *could* manually use a more absolute URL (`/Home/Test`), but that will only work if the site is on the server's root, so it's not as portable.

Comment: I tried <%= Url.Action("Test", "Home") %> but im getting a syntax exception because of the comma (,)

Comment: @BuyMyBet: What's throwing the syntax error?  Is it server-side or client-side?  It sounds like something might be wrong with your overall setup in that the view isn't being pre-processed correctly.  Do you use any other server-side code in your view?

Comment: no just a script tag...I updated my script as you told me in my post

Comment: @BuyMyBet: You forgot the quotes around the server-side code.  The quotes are for JavaScript's benefit, not for the server-side benefit.  The resulting URL is still a string from JavaScript's perspective and needs to be handled as such.

Comment: @BuyMyBet: And if you're still getting an error, you'll want to test that you can do any server-side code *at all* in your view.  If not, something else is wrong.  For now you can just hard-code `"/Home/Test"` in the JavaScript code to get going on this one issue, but not being able to pre-process server-side code in your view will result in a lot more problems as you continue development.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this in MVC but I've done this countless times in Web Forms and it looks like your URL might be the problem...

**//localhost:9819/Home/Home/Test**

In your ajax call you should probably adjust this line...

```
url: "Home/Test"
```

and make it look something like ...

```
url: <%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Home/Test.asmx") %>
```

Sorry if this is way off base for MVC.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Yeah, that comes down to my inexperience with MVC.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your button type to 'button' not submit as this is ajax call